# On event that happens in child , I need to change state which is stored in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner to React.
On event that happens in child `<MyInput>`, I need to change state which is stored in parent `<audienceContainer>`. Below is my code snippet.

Have the following hierarchy of components:

```
-audienceContainer
  -audienceForm
   -MyInput
```

In audienceContainer, which is parent:

```
handlValidationErrors(obj, changedItem, value) {
        //some code
    }
   render() {

        return (
  <AudienceForm 
      onErrorAppear = {this.handlValidationErrors.bind(this, changedItem, value)} 
   />
)}
```

In AudienceForm, which is child:

```
...
onErrorAppear(obj, changedItem, value)
    {
        this.props.onErrorAppear(obj, changedItem, value);
    }

...
 render () {
        return (
 <MyInput 
    onErrorAppear = {this.onErrorAppear.bind(this, changedItem, value)}
  />
}
```

In child of child MyInput:

```
 ...
isValid(input) {
       ...
      this.props.onErrorAppear(input, input.props.errorField, 'Field is not valid'); //!!!!!
     ...}
```

So I got error "changedItem is not defined" in  audienceContainer.
Maybe somebody can help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply some value to the changedItem. Ditto with value.

```
<AudienceForm 
   onErrorAppear = {this.handleValidationErrors.bind(this, changedItem, value)} 
/>
```

If this is something that the child component will do on method call, don't bind.

```
<AudienceForm 
   onErrorAppear = {this.handleValidationErrors.bind(this)} 
/>
```